# Why is a new project with the same app ID still designated a new location?

Tags: ios, app-id

We have created a new project with the same app ID, but this is designated a different folder in isolated storage. Why is this?

> file:///Users/houman/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FBFFFF1E-B5C8-4541-AB4B-ED1657D43EB9/data/Containers/Data/Application/EB3A549F-1604-4E5C-8FBE-3076A3D581E5/Documents/
>
> file:///Users/houman/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FBFFFF1E-B5C8-4541-AB4B-ED1657D43EB9/data/Containers/Data/Application/22E1E792-1F4F-4F05-B7D9-F61AD3624EE9/Documents/

Even though the apps share the same ID.
Since they don’t share the same location, no core data migration can take place.
Any advice please?

**Update:**
We have two apps in the AppStore and would like to combine the functionality. Hence the idea is to use the appID of the other app to push a new release from a separate project.  We have the appID and right certificates, but the isolated storage seems to depend on something else than just appid. Without that a migration of existing data to the new system won't be possible.  Alternatively we could copy and paste all files into the other project and go through lots of pain. That might make it possible.

Comment: A different project, a different location, makes sense. Just try moving the CoreData file or create a process to repopulate the Core Data file.

Comment: If this behaviour was only limited within the simulator, it would been alright to move the coredata as you suggested.  But deploying it via crashlytics to the actual device, indicates the same problem.

Comment: Did you change the simulator?

Comment: Why is someone downvoting this, without providing any comment? This is a genuine problem and I can explain further if required.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this on my end - I believe (and could be wrong) that each simulator you run in gets its own folder on the disk.  If you switch for iPhone 5 to iPhone 6s for example you may end up with a different folder.

I always actually (when running in the simulator) print out the on-disk location so that I can take a look at the `sqlite` file if i need to and recently (as of xcode7) i've noticed this directory change between runs - however in my case i tracked it down to changing simulator versions.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I just tried it without success. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly for security reasons. Every iOS application is placed in an application sandbox.

This not only refer to an application's sandbox directory in the file system, granting security by limiting the access to user data stored on the device, system services, and hardware.